# Funcion que genera una contraseña aleatoria - problema

Tags: javascript, funciones

Estaba haciendo una funcion que me retorna una contraseña aleatoria con numeros, y letras en mayusculas y minusculas. El problema es que me coloca un 'Undefined' o 'NaN', al inicio.

Las operaciones que hago, para generar la contraseña:

```
const minus="abcdefghijklmnñopqrstuvwxyz";
const mayus="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNÑOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    
for(var i=1; i<=8; i++)
{
    var eleccion = Math.floor(Math.random()*3+1);

    if(eleccion==1)
    {
        var caracter1=minus.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random()*minus.length));
        contraseña+=caracter1;
    }

    else
    {
        if(eleccion==2)
        {
            var caracter2=mayus.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random()*mayus.length));
            contraseña+=caracter2;
        }

        else
        {
            var num=Math.floor(Math.random()*10);

            contraseña+=num;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Si `eleccion = 3` entonces `contraseña` va a ser igual a que ?? Contraseña no está definido para empezar.

Comment: @Excorpion Supongamos que el OP define una variable contraseña, acabo de probar el código del OP y en efecto, causa NaN y undefined.

Comment: La solución en este caso sería hacer un for con un array de todas las letras del abecedario haciendo que el for pare en la cantidad de caracteres que se desean

Comment: Además hay un error de sintaxis, la elección siempre será 3.

Comment: Yo probé `eleccion`, sus valores obtenibles son 1, 2 y 3

Comment: El _undefined_ es porque no has definido `contraseña`. Antes del ciclo, agrega: `let contraseña = '';`

Comment: Fue lo primero que dije !!!

Comment: Porque lo editan definiendo la variable? Si ese es el principal error

Comment: No la definí, sólo la *declaré*. Eso no modifica el comportamiento

Comment: Esa edición que le hicieron al código de la pregunta es la cosa más sospechosamente incorrecta que he visto en 2021. No se entiende por qué le editaron el código que puso.

Comment: Varios advertimos el movimiento de @PabloLozano, en el chat y en estos comentarios le hemos dicho lo mismo. Ahora devolvió el código a su original pero dejando el `console.log()` que agregó al final. Lo cuál también me parece un agregado de su parte...

Comment: Mi intención era que el código sea ejecutable en la propia pregunta, para que se pudiese ver el problema. He eliminado la declaración de la variable (que no inicializaba nada, pero así evitamos suspicacias) para dejarlo como estaba.

Answer (score 4):

Tal parece que estás empleando mal los `Math`, si quieres generar un string random, puedes obtener el abecedario entero para luego hacer un `for` elijiendo un número random con `Math` para obtener índices aleatorios del abecedario

```js
const generarString = (longitud) => {
  let result = "";
  const abc = "a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z".split(" "); // Espacios para convertir cara letra a un elemento de un array
  for(i=0;i<=longitud;i++) {
    const random = Math.floor(Math.random() * abc.length);
    result += abc[random]
  }
  return result;
};

console.log(generarString(20))
```

Si lo que buscas es intercalarlo con minúsculas, mayúsculas, puedes hacer otro `Math` para elejir el caso

```js
const generarString = (longitud) => {
  let result = "";
  const abc = "a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z".split(" "); // Espacios para convertir cara letra a un elemento de un array
  for(i=1;i<=longitud;i++) {
    if (abc[i]) { // Condicional para prevenir errores en caso de que longitud sea mayor a 26
      const random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4); // Generaremos el número
      const random2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * abc.length); // Generaremos el número
      const random3 = Math.floor(Math.random() * abc.length + 3); // Generaremos el número
      if (random == 1) {
        result += abc[random2]
      } else if (random == 2) {
        result += random3 + abc[random2]
      } else {
        result += abc[random2].toUpperCase()
      }
    }
  }
  return result;
};

console.log(generarString(20))
```

Comment: me gusta no tener dos strings pudiendo usar `.toUpperCase()`

Comment: Los números siempre corresponden al valor de `i`, no son al azar y, además, se agrega con 1 o más dígitos y un caracter adicional.

Answer (score 3):

Si bien ya lo dijeron en los comentarios, quiero ponerlo como respuesta para resumirlo.

El error esta en que no estas definiendo la variable `contraseña` con **un valor inicial** esto para que valla agregandose los caracteres a la variable. Solo definela, en mi caso como `vacio` (`''`)

```js
const minus = "abcdefghijklmnñopqrstuvwxyz";
const mayus = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNÑOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

var contraseña = '';

for (var i = 1; i <= 8; i++) {
  var eleccion = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3 + 1);

  if (eleccion == 1) {
    var caracter1 = minus.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * minus.length));
    contraseña += caracter1;
  } else {
    if (eleccion == 2) {
      var caracter2 = mayus.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * mayus.length));
      contraseña += caracter2;
    } else {
      var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);

      contraseña += num;
    }
  }

}

console.log(contraseña);
```

Aunque una recomendacion seria no definir variables con caracteres especiales, en vez de eso puede ser simplemente `clave`

Answer (score 2):

El problema es que no has inicializado la variable contraseña, por lo que su valor es undefined, y si miramos lo que pasa cuando a undefined le intentas sumar algo...

```js
let valor = undefined + 1;

console.log(valor);
```

Por tanto, basta con dar un valor inicial a esa variable de *cadena vacía* (`""`) para que funcione:

```js
const minus = "abcdefghijklmnñopqrstuvwxyz";
const mayus = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNÑOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

let contraseña = "";
for (let i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
  let eleccion = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3 + 1);
  if (eleccion == 1) {
    let caracter1 = minus.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * minus.length));
    contraseña += caracter1;
  } else if (eleccion == 2) {
    const caracter2 = mayus.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * mayus.length));
    contraseña += caracter2;
  } else {
    let num = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
    contraseña += num;
  }
}

console.log(contraseña);
```

Comment: jajajaj Quede en las mismas. Ya lo habia probado asi normal, pero el problema es que lo que comparti es un fragmento de un metodo, en una classe. Entonces el metodo dentro de la clase, es el que no me funciona.